# SearchBar TintColor no applied correct

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, colors, uisearchbar

I have a problem with the TintColor of my SearchBar. I use the same RGB Color in the navigation bar and on the searchbar. As you can see below, the colors are not the same.

[image]

This is the code I use to set the TintColor of the navigationbar:

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:34/255.0f green:113/255.0f blue:179/255.0f alpha:1];
```

and this is what I use to set the TintColor of the searchBar.

```
    self.mySearchBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:34/255.0f green:113/255.0f blue:179/255.0f alpha:1];
```

So, as you can see, those two lines are pretty much the same. Any ideas on how to get the same color?

Any advice as very appreciated!

**Edit**:
I develop for iOS 4.0 with XCode 4.3.3 and i tested on a device with iOS 5

Comment: It may help to tell us on which version you're developing / testing.

Comment: I develop for iOS 4.0 with XCode 4.3.3 and i tested on a device with iOS 5, thank you, I edited my post

Comment: Thanks, it may help to replicate the situation. In fact, I did a quick test, on iOS 5.1 and it seems to work fine... Can you try with iOS 5.1+ ?

Comment: didn't work on iOS 6.0 as well. Problem solved with the code below! Thank you :-)!

Comment: Maybe you can find answer for your question [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19976372/2012219

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had similar issue and this is what I ended up doing then,

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:34/255.0f green:113/255.0f blue:179/255.0f alpha:1]]];
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:34/255.0f green:113/255.0f blue:179/255.0f alpha:1]] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But the problem with this approach was that it will not be tinted exactly.

**Update:**
`imageWithColor` is category on `UIImage`.

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: And did you find the origin of the problem ?

Comment: No. In my case this issue was coming only in iOS 6 device. It was working fine in other devices. That's what I remember.

Comment: That works for me. Nice idea! imageWithColor should be added to the library :-)!

Comment: Forgot to mention. imageWithColor was category added on UIImage. Updated answer with code for that.