# iOS7, backgroundImage for UISearchBar

Tags: ios, ios7, uikit, transition, searchbar

I'm making the transition of the UI between iOS 6 and iOS 7.

We have a UISearchBar related to a UISearchDisplayController, I have set the backgroundImage of the navigationBar and the searchBar to a 1x1 image dynamically created with a color.

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.translucent = NO;
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor myTintColor];
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.backgroundImage = [self imageWithColor:[UIColor myBGColor]];
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.scopeBarBackgroundImage = [self imageWithColor:[UIColor myBGColor]];
```

On iOS6, everything works as expected. 
On iOS7, when the searchBar is selected, the scopeBar appears with the good backgroundImage (set with searchBar.scopeBarBackgroundImage) but the searchBar is a kind of translucent gray. When I press on Cancel, the searchBar backgroundImage is back.

[image: How it looks]

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

EDITED QUESTION

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Actually, I did use the barTintColor and other options here and there but it doesn't work. That is the result with the barTintColor set with the same color. But there is this white layer on top
[image]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In iOS 7, the properties `backgroundImage` and `scopeBarBackgroundImage` no longer work as expected and become translucent.

The following method has been introduced in iOS 7 which addresses this problem. **(Docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISearchBar/setBackgroundImage:forBarPosition:barMetrics:]))**

```
setBackgroundImage:forBarPosition:barMetrics:
```

Here's what you should do :

```
 [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor yourColor]] 
                                             forBarPosition:0 
                                                 barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Here, `barPosition : 0` is `UIBarPositionAny`.

*Edit:*

Swift code:

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.setBackgroundImage(self.image(color: UIColor.yourColor), for: UIBarPosition(rawValue: 0)!, barMetrics:.default)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but unfortunately it doesn't change!

Comment: Check out the edited answer and tell me if it works!

Comment: You made it! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I 've been looking for ages, this answer helps a lot!

Comment: spend half a day - you really save my time!

Answer (score 4):

I was able to replicate what you were trying to do and it seems to work for me if I set the `barTintColor` to my color choice.

I'd suggest trying:

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor myBGColor];
```

I did `[UIColor redColor]` and got the results I expected.

Comment: I edited my question with the screenshot of the result. It's not what I expect, did you have the same result?

Comment: It shouldn't be doing what you are showing if you have `translucent` set to `NO` as it appears you do. It looks like you are using an image for your color, have you tried just using a solid color, such as `[UIColor blueColor]`

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `barTintColor` property of your search bar, you will get what you are expecting. I've just tried this and it works:

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

Keep in mind that `barTintColor` property was introduced in iOS 7.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I edited my question with the screenshot of the result. It's not what I expect, did you have the same result?

Comment: There isn't a white layer, its looking that way because it is translucent. Try this ``self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.translucent = NO;``

Comment: Unfortunately, it's already the case. It seems that this searchBar is broken

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. `UISearchBar` doesn't seem to respect its `translucent` property.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no current Swift version, I'll just leave this here for future use, as I have been struggling with it for pretty long time as well.

1. get yourself 1px image with desired color (even clear)
2. set it as a backgroundImage using:

   `searchController.searchBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "red"), for: .any, barMetrics: .default)`