# UISearchBar and/or UISearchDisplayController color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

UPDATE: Thanks for all the answers. I would like to add that the search bar used is actually a `UISearchBar` embedded as part of `UISearchDisplayController` that is set to the a `UITableView`'s header.

I've created a sample project exhibiting this behavior here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3497087/TestSearchDisplayController.zip. I tried setting the `barTintColor` to blue and black. The most obvious thing is that when setting to black, I get a grayish bar.

I appreciate all answers and ideas, thank you.

---

I am working on skinning the app that I'm currently working on, and I seem to hit a roadblock with `UISearchBar` and/or `UISearchDisplayController` bar color.

The first issue I have revolves around setting the `barTintColor` for `UISearchBar` that is attached as a `tableview header`. I've set it to blackColor in Interface Builder. However, when the app runs, the color doesn't seem to be black, but some sort of gray, with an ugly white line above! I've tried setting this thru code, but that doesn't seem to help too. See screenshots below.

[image: UISearchBar barTintColor set to black in IB]

[image: UISearchBar barTintColor when running on simulator]

My second question revolves around `UISearchDisplayController`. I wanted black color when the search display controller takes over the top of the screen. I've tried setting the color code, but the only color that it won't take is, again, black color!

[image]

Comment: use TintColor property instead of barTintColor

Comment: @Sunnyshah tintColor will not change the bar color, but will instead change the text color for the Cancel bar button item.

Comment: Try to change color of UINavigationBar with black color and check.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 [[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"black"]];
```

[image]

check out your [sample project](https://github.com/iDevAndroid/TestSearchDisplayController)

[image]

Comment: Yup, that's the issue I'm facing. If I detach the UISearchBar from the searchDisplayController, I can skin it properly. But that means I lose the functionality that came with the searchDisplayController.

Comment: because the search display controller have self translucent effort

Comment: do you know if it's possible to change that?

Comment: after dismiss pulldown tableview to able see searchbar

Comment: Sorry, I upvoted, but forgot to click on the tick to accept. Done. Thanks again!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45440/discussion-between-xcool-and-idev)

Answer (score 5):

You can try with this:

```
_searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor]; // change the barColor     
_searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; // change the title color
```

Answer (score 3):

It's as simple as setting `searchBar.barTintColor` to the color you want. No need for images. `searchBar.tintColor` changes the color of the Cancel button.

Answer (score 3):

I just add a helper function to set everything, including the cancel button color (tint.color). This called in ViewDidLoad:

```
//Set the searchbar settings, delegates
func setSearchBar() {

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Enter Search Text"
    searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 72/255, green: 100/255, blue: 156/255, alpha: 1)
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white

    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
}
```

You can also set own color for searchbar color (barTintColor). This works in Xcode 8 and Swift 3.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, I had the same issue few months ago. Have a look at: [iOS7, backgroundImage for UISearchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927542/ios7-backgroundimage-for-uisearchbar)
At the end, it uses the method:

```
setBackgroundImage:forBarPosition:barMetrics:
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting control of the iOS 7 search bar background color is tricky. The easiest and most reliable approach: Make a solid black image and call `setBackgroundImage:forBarPosition:barMetrics:`. (Getting the second and third arguments right is also tricky!) Also explicitly set the bar's `translucent` to NO just to be on the safe side. Do all this in code; do not rely on Interface Builder to get things right.

Answer (score 0):

## For Background Color of Searchbar  :

[image]

[image]

### For TintColor:

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score -3):

Hi You can try with this

```
 _searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    _searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _searchBar.backgroundImage = nil;
```

Comment: You need to use the barTintColor property for ios7. thanks dear

Comment: don't give a reputation it totally irreverent to above question